# C# File not found exeption

Tags: c#, io

I have added a file to my solution:

[image]

I am trying to access the file though the namespace as:-

xxx.Toolbox.ProductMigration54.UnitTest.TestData.FlexCredit_IsUltimoFalse_360_360.xml

but I get the error message :

[image]

when I check if the file exists, i can see that it does:

[image]

I have been looking at this for a while and cant get to the bottom of it.

Comment: When you select the file in Visual Studio and look at its properties, what is the Build Action for this file?

Comment: I just changed that to Embedded resource and rebuilt but am still getting the error

Comment: The exception window you show is for a different file thab the one you show in the visual studio ide image.

Answer (score 0):

What about file open-attributes (file-mode): 
a) write instead of readonly?
b) exclusive instead of shared access?
c) What is the File open+read C# Codeline?